# How to call a Python Firebase Function from React-Native?

Tags: python, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

StackOverflow community , I've created  two Python functions, 'onCall' and 'onRequest,' which appear as follows:

```
from firebase_functions import firestore_fn, https_fn
import fitz
import re
import requests
import io
from datetime import datetime
# The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, firestore, credentials, storage 
import google.cloud.firestore
from google.cloud import storage as Storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from uuid import uuid4

cred = credentials.Certificate("credits/myProject.json")
app = initialize_app(cred,{'storageBucket':'myProject.appspot.com'})

@https_fn.on_call()
def sendHelloOnCall(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("HELLO", status=200)

@https_fn.on_request()
def sendHello(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("HELLO", status=200)
```

Successfully, I've deployed these functions in Cloud Functions. Now, I aim to utilize them within my React-Native app, where my main screen implementation resembles this:

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

export function Home({navigation}) {
  functions()
    .httpsCallable('sendHelloOnCall')()
    .then(r => {
      console.log(r);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  functions()
    .httpsCallable('sendHello')()
    .then(r => {
      console.log(r);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });    
    return(
    <>
      <></>
    </>
    );
}
```

However, I encounter the following issues:

For 'sendHelloOnCall', I receive an error message: [Error: INTERNAL].

For 'sendHello', I receive an error message: [Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.].

My primary question is, what might I be doing incorrectly?

Additionally, I attempted to send a request from Postman to the 'sendHello' function. It returns "HELLO" in the response. However, for 'sendHelloOnCall', I receive the following:

> {"error": {"message": "Bad Request","status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

I'm seeking guidance on these matters. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install axios
```

after

```
import axios from 'axios';

function post() {
    const myURL =
      'https://yourHttps.net/sendHello';
    const options = {
      your_params:'',
    };
    axios
      .post(`${myURL}`, null, {params: options})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```